# What is the best way to play Mario Kart Double Dash with 8-16 people?

Tags: mario-kart-double-dash

I would like to play with 8-16 of my friends on Mario Kart Double Dash. I am currently trying to calculate the best way to accomplish this. I currently have 2 GameCubes and 6 original controllers, I also have two PC controllers and several computers. So far there seems to be three choices:

- Buy 2 more GameCubes, 10 more controllers, and 2-4 LAN adapters at $40 each.
- Buy several Wiis which have cheaper LAN adapters ($20?) and controllers.
- Buy lots of PC controllers and use some kind of emulator and the existing towers I already have (not sure if this is even an option).

Using the GameCubes I think I would have the most stable environment since that is the initial platform. However, using PC's I could use the same setup for multiple games which would justify the cost more.

Has anyone ever done this? Are their any DIY guides to handle some parts of the setup?

Comment: The Wii LAN adapter cannot be used for GameCube games, nor can you use a GameCube LAN adapter with a Wii. You need an actual GameCube to do networking with GameCube games.

Comment: Is my answer insufficient or have you just lost interest in this?  Would love a check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest and cheapest way to do it would be with the GameCubes. You can buy them and controllers on eBay and yard sales for cheaper and cheaper every day, whereas the Wii is newer and will continue to stay at a higher cost for a while.

Either way, if you're comparing cost-wise, I would just look up both on eBay, Amazon, and simply to Google to find the cheapest of each you can get and then just to compare prices and just buy the cheaper.

The PC option wouldn't really be worth it because the experience is a lot different since you'd be emulating it somehow. The GameCube would still apply to other games too since you can always just buy another game for it...

Comment: I agree with this answer, but also for anyone coming to this question in the future, it seems difficult to find any Gamecube Broadband Adapters for anything under $50 US. I don't know how cheap it would be to buy two of everything and make sure you have 8 controllers, no less 4 and 16...

Comment: @timelord67 You guys having fun?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 You guys having fun?

Answer (score -3):

watch this video and it will show you how to do it on PC with the Dolphin emulator

Comment: Could you summarise the content of the video in case it is removed in future?  You can always [edit] your answer to include this information.

Comment: +1 Using a VPN between the computers involved, run the Dolphin emulator.